# IT Security and Ethical Hacking

Tags: penetration-test

Hello, programmers, security professionals, hackers and everyone who is interested in information security. I am taking security courses in my university but I found there is only lab so I have to learn by myself, there will not be any tutorials. So I want to ask you. Can anyone recommend any ethical hacking, it security courses? Has anyone attendend www.thehackeracademy.com. Does it worth its price? Thank you for any information beforehand.

Comment: There are a range of courses in many countries - you really need to look locally, speak to your course leader and discuss your needs from a course. Security Stackexchange isn't a suitable place to ask this sort of question (it comes under 'subjective') so I'll have to close. Have a look at http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3592 though, which may be of interest.

Answer (score 3):

first suggestion: this thread will get better responses over "https://security.stackexchange.com/", so get it moved there

**answer:**

I've been a self-learner of Security for long time, and from my own (and other security enthusiasts I know) experience I can say that you don't need to take any paid course to learn about Security..... actually that might give you a good boot-up but there are lots of free/open resources which would help you do the same.

I'd say start following blogs/tweets of good Security Experts that you can get hold of. Follow what's being discussed in Security Conferences (like DefCon, BlackHat, ShmooCon & more), you can even get loads of videos from these conferences on Youtube, Vimeo and their respective site.

I did started with a very basic intro guide (an open-content e-book) to hacking, but it's in its initial stages..... if you wanna keep a tab on it and follow up, the link is

Link:  https://github.com/abhishekkr/eden_guide_to_hacking

until now I've covered:: 
part.0 Fundamentals, 
part.1 Hacking Cycle step.0 Acquiring Target, and
part.1 Hacking Cycle step.1 Reconnaisance [Active Recon, Passive Recon]

~~~~~

apart from learning basics, also keep track of what's going on in Security Arena from portals like

Link: http://threatpost.com/en_us

Link: http://www.exploit-db.com/

**and for any query you can always post it on https://security.stackexchange.com/**

Answer (score 2):

Google has example app with many vulnerabilities - [Gruyere](http://google-gruyere.appspot.com)
Many good papers on security can be found in [BlackHat Archives](https://www.blackhat.com/html/archives.html)

Answer (score 0):

Security field has many different sides, depending on what you want to work with later you should pick courses.

They only course I can personally recommend is very technical, and it is on pen-test side, they will not teach you how to configure firewall or write security policy but instead you will see world from hackers perspective: OSCP

http://www.offensive-security.com/information-security-certifications/

PS: Of course there are other courses that also great. I am sure there will be a lot of other abbreviations  :)