# Which CTF Penetration Test?

Tags: penetration-test

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What “hacking” competitions/challenges exist?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3592/what-hacking-competitions-challenges-exist)

I want to test my penetration test skills.And i solved a few CTF.But it is not enough.I want to solve more ctf test.

Please advice me.

Answer (score 4):

OWASP has a couple of very interesting resources of this kind:

- [Hacme Bank](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_O2_Platform/WIKI/Using_O2_on%3a_HacmeBank): a banking application built with some vulnerabilities for you to find and try to exploit
- [The WebGoat Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_WebGoat_Project): web application with several vulnerabilities. Every possible attack is explained in a specific lesson, so that you can concentrate on one technique at the time