# Sites to test login through jmeter

Tags: firefox, html

Im having a hard time looking for a site with a login system that can be probed with firebug, the POST request password specifically, i was just wondering if anyone here knows one or two sites that are open for testing or just dont encrypt the passwords, thanks.

Comment: there are lots of 'hackable' sites where they give you permission to hack them: have you looked up those sites? Or were you hoping a real site was going to give you permission to hack them?

Comment: Hahaha the first one of course, i dont know if its really hacking, just want to sent a POST request via jMeter but it doesnt seem to work by filling the request manually so im trying get the data with firebug.

Comment: In some jurisdictions, even using firebug to manipulate POST is considered "hacking" - so you should probably look for sites that give you permission. Google "hackable sites" to get these kinds of sites (you'll have to see if they have a login type you need).

Comment: whoa.. didnt know (sorry NSA), should have guessed that google provided something like that, thanks!

Comment: starting a local http server that accepts post requests should not take more than 5 minutes, unless I am not understanding what you are trying to do?

Comment: Running a web server on your now computer is best. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365309/where-can-i-find-a-deliberately-insecure-open-source-web-application

Comment: related : http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3592/what-hacking-competitions-challenges-exist ,this gives u the list of sites were you can play around ,