# Any CTF sites besides CTF365

Tags: ctf

I am looking for free ctf sites like ctf365, but I want a challenge and not vulnerable-by-design machines. Any references?

Comment: You seem to be asking for a structured, progressive hackable series of targets, but where the targets are not vulnerable by design? I'm not sure such a thing could possibly exist. If you are looking for a challenge, you might troll exploit sites and apply the PoCs to the targets.

Comment: Maybe some of the challenges from this question are of interest? http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3592/what-hacking-competitions-challenges-exist

Comment: Just take a look at this https://ctftime.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here there are a lot of .iso containing ctf:
https://www.vulnhub.com/
there a lot, some are stupid , others are more interesting.

Then there is exploit-exercises.com that has some very good ctf box.
Another is www.root-me.org that has a lot of challange and some ctf too.
Anyway, a ctf that is "not vulnerable by design" doesn't exists. You can take some open source project and try too find some vuln, or maybe look
for https://bugcrowd.com/ , that lists all bug bounties